# Count number of elements in array after placing them in ascending order

Tags: c

I'm creating a program that reads input from an array and orders it in an ascending order. However, I also wanted to count the number of times each element appears in the array, but I'm struggling to to this. This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef enum _ordem {
    Crescente=1
} ordem;

void troca(int *x, int *y){
    int wk;
    wk=*x;*x=*y;*y=wk;
}

int trocar(int x, int y, ordem dir){
    if(dir == Crescente)
        return x > y;
    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(int *array, int top, int fim, ordem dir){
    int i, j, trocado;
    for(i = top; i < fim; ++i){
        trocado = 0;
        for(j = top + 1; j <= fim - i; ++j)
            if(trocar(array[j-1], array[j], dir)){
                troca(&array[j-1], &array[j]);
                trocado = 1;
            }
        if(trocado == 0)break;
    }
}

int main(){
    int vetor[100], index, ordem=1;
    index=0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    printf("Introduza os números. Escreva -00 para parar. \n");
    do{
        scanf("%d", &vetor[index++]);
    }while(vetor[index-1] != -00 && index < 100);
    --index;

    bubbleSort(vetor, 0, index-1, ordem);
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<index;++i)
            printf("%d ", vetor[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you think you could count how many times the first element appears? Do you have any ideas about that? After you have counted the first element, how do you think you could count how many times the second element appears? What about the third? When would you be done?

Comment: (By the way, `scanf` does not distinguish between “-00” and “0” in input. Both will result in zero being assigned. `-00` in C source code is just zero.)

Comment: Honestly, I have no clue how to do it, I can get the position of x number in the array but not count how many times it's there

Comment: Tip: Don't stack up multiple statements on the same line. This doesn't help readability. It doesn't make your code faster.

Comment: Why is there a random scoped block after `bubbleSort`? Just put `for (int i = 0; ...)` and you can get that scoped for free.

Answer (score 0):

After the numbers have been sorted, equal numbers will be next to each other in the array.  This makes it easy to count the number of times each number occurs using a single loop that iterates through the sorted array, with an extra variable that is incremented when the next element has the same number as the current element, or is reset when the next element has a different number.

The following block of code will do that:

```
    {
        int i, c;
        c = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
            if (i < index - 1 && vetor[i] == vetor[i + 1]) {
                c++;
            } else {
                printf("%d(x%d) ", vetor[i], c);
                c = 1;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

You could create another array to store a table of the unique values with their frequency of occurrance:

```
    struct freq {
        int val;
        int freq;
    };
    struct freq freq[100];
    int nfreq = 0;
```

Fill the table using a loop similar to the earlier code:

```
    {
        int i, c;
        c = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
            if (i < index - 1 && vetor[i] == vetor[i + 1]) {
                c++;
            } else {
                freq[nfreq].val = vetor[i];
                freq[nfreq].freq = c;
                nfreq++;
                c = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Print the out the table with another simple loop:

```
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < nfreq; i++) {
            printf("%d(x%d) ", freq[i].val, freq[i].freq);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```